# Kubernetes dashboard on vSphere, fresh install gives "no route to host"

Tags: kubernetes, vsphere

This was taken from [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24407) (issue #24407) to Stackoverflow.

Even with the commit from Friday, May 6th 2016 (commit c11229f) to `cluster/vsphere`, this error

`Error: 'dial tcp 172.17.0.2:9090: no route to host'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.17.0.2:9090/'`

remains.
I tried on a fresh install of VMware vSphere ESXi 6.0.0; installed k8s with the standard `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vsphere cluster/kube-up.sh` and the script finished with positive results, this time with "kubernetes-dashboard" enabled from the start:

`Cluster validation succeeded
Done, listing cluster services:`

`Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.1.36
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.1.36/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://192.168.1.36/api/v1/proxy  /namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard`

Yet still unable to connect to the dashboard from my Mac with the infamous "no route to host"...

Am I mistakenly under the impression that a k8s installation should work out of the box on VMware vSphere?
Or is e.g. the lack of an external IP a probable cause in this? (if so I need to find out how to enable one - am under the impression kube-proxy is taking care of stuff)

`$ kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns               10.244.240.240   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   2h
kubernetes-dashboard   10.244.240.121   <none>        80/TCP          2h`

Comment: If you run `kubectl proxy` are you able to access the dashboard at http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy  /namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard ?

Comment: No. When start a proxy like that on my Mac, I get the message: "the server could not find the requested resource". When using port 9090 the "no route to host" is there (again).